# ios - how do I tell what string is returned in AFNetworking remote call

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have this code in case of failure:

```
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
```

and I want to log the string that is returned. Out of which variable should I do that and how?

Comment: Please open a new question for your edit - while it's related to your original question, it isn't the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So typically you want to print the error, this will print any thing that your server is reporting as an error. Failure messages are triggered when it received the wrong type it was expecting (plaintext instead of application/json) or if the status code is >400 like (404, 401) stuff like that.

If you're doing error checking you should either set the statuscode in the response header and then compare it to `response.statusCode` or most likely when you are returning data you should error check in the success block.

If you absolutely need to access the responseString from the response you can use `operation.responseString` where operation is the AF Request Operation.

**update**

here is an example from @mattt at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/137:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Friend Request Sent");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[Error]: (%@ %@) %@", [operation.request HTTPMethod], [[operation.request URL] relativePath], operation.error);
}];
```

Comment: the status returned is actually 200 but the second line which is this: NSLog(operation.responseString); is crashing...am I not using it correctly?

Comment: and it is crashing with a weird error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIRoundedRectButton responseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x714eb00'
 ....why would it point to a UIRoundedRectButton?

Comment: I'm not sure, it probably has to do something with calling the operation in the instantiation of the object. You can use a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` initialize that then use the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:Failure:` method on the operation object. which will return with an operation parameter. The downside is I don't think you can convert the data to JSON automatically so you will have to parse it yourself.